# Javascript structured error handling

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I am developing my first Javascript app and I am trying to go object oriented.
There is a basic closure that returns my primary object and every function I invoke rests in that object. Some pseudo code would look like this:

```
primary = (function(){
var object = {
     doSomething = function(){};
},  
return {intance:function(return object)}
});

//invocation
primary.instance().doSomething();
```

What I am trying to achieve is to attach an error handler function to my `object`, so that whenever there is an internal error, it is cought, and I don't have to wrap every function call in a `try` `catch` block.

I tried `object.onerror`but the `error` went on to `window object`. Maybe I am getting the concept wrong. I tried searching on Github for some simpler framework that includes structured error handling, but no luck. I am pretty familiar with this in PHP, but I haven't done this so far in Javascript. Can somebody show me an example how it is done right?

EDIT: I know that structured error handling goes further, I am just trying to get a root handler, so that no errors / exceptions can pass on to the `window object`

Comment: Depends on what your goal is, but I think you're doing it wrong, and getting it wrong. You're creating a God object that does everything, which usually isn't a good thing, and in javascript errors generally halt execution, which is fine and shouldn't generally warrant a try/catch block for every conceivable error. If you're expecting errors, deal with those where they occur, otherwise assume your code works.

Comment: is doSomething throwing an error or some service inside? as you do not pass any arguments in the method I assume it is another service perhaps asynchronous - in that case you should not throw error as doSomething will finish execution before error happens.

Comment: Disregarding the design patterns used for your app and how to implement your error handler, there are lots of syntax errors in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with the `error` event without a try catch block *will* halt the execution of your script (except for any asynchronous functions that have already been called).

You can suppress (non-ajax, non-syntax) errors by capturing them on `document.body` or a more specific object, and stop them being thrown to the user (or reaching the `window` object) by using `e.preventDefault()` or `return false`, and send them to a global/object handler (to inspect or log) by passing the event object as an argument - but any of those options will stop your script execution beyond the point of error. That's the main benefit of a try catch block, and as far as I know there is no way around that.